# Positioned div elements

Tags: jquery, css, html

I've seen the following on a few websites and I was wondering how it is done..

http://www.peterurban.info/

Basically it is a number of various height divs all positioned within a container which seems to have an inline height style in order to create the space for the positioned divs. I don't think it is javascript (looked in inspector). Maybe it's some kind of php trick? Styles must be injected from the DOM though?

If anyone can share any light on this that would be great.

Comment: see this also [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#fluidGridSystem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The have done it with this jquery plugin: http://masonry.desandro.com/